# Access control based on session

Tags: users, sessions

Currently I am making a website for restaurants. In the site, each restaurant is a node type and a menu item is another node type. The relationship between restaurant and menu items is one to many.

What I am doing is that after user creates and saves a restaurant node, the user session will keep the newly-created restaurant node id, based on that id, user can create multiple menu items for this restaurant.

What I want to make is that only when there is a restaurant id in user's session can user go to menu item add page, otherwise they cannot do that.

So how can I add this menu-item-add-page access control based on user's session?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Node Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_limit) and [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) for this... something like:

- limit the user to creating one node (restaurant) type
- create a field for the user, alter its access using Field Permissions, so they can't see or change it
- use Rules on the event of new content created (restaurant), assign that user Field the node id of the newly created node
- using Rules again, assign the appropriate field in any further node creation (menu item) using the user field value (which now contains the node id of the restaurant)
- using Rules again, check url for /node/[menu-item]/add and see if that user has a user field containing a node id - if no id, redirect to a message screen saying they have to create a restaurant first

In this way, you limit each user to one restaurant, assign a permanent value to that user for the restaurant they create, and make some checks to ensure they have an assigned node id before they are able to create a menu item.

Rules:

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module

Node LImit:

> The Node Limit module allows administrators to restrict the number of
>   nodes of a specific type that roles or users may create. For example,
>   if a site has an "Advertiser" role that can create "advertisement"
>   nodes, then the node limit administrator can restrict all users in
>   that role to a specific number of nodes. He may also restrict users on
>   a per-user basis.

Field Permissions

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.